# How to show / hide the second div by hovering the first one?

Tags: jquery, mouseover, show-hide, mouseout

The following code works fine but there is a little problem I couldn't fix.

While div2 is on show, by moving the mouse pointer inside its containing links (from one link to another), it gets hidden.

What's wrong and how to fix?

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div>
        <span id="div1">User Name</span>
        <section id="div2">
            <a id="lnkLogin" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a id="lnkStatus" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            jQuery('#div2').hide(); jQuery('#div1').mouseover(function () {
                jQuery('#div2').fadeIn();
            });
            jQuery('#div2').mouseout(function () {
                jQuery('#div2').fadeOut();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/uzq6jfmo/)

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Just replace `.mouseout` with `.mouseleave`: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzq6jfmo/3/).

Comment: @Regent: I replaced them but didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `#div2` inside `#div1`:

```
<div> 
    <span id="div1">User Name
        <section id="div2"> 
            <a id="lnkLogin" href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a id="lnkStatus" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </section>
    </span>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/uzq6jfmo/2)

Note that I've changed to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to prevent repetitious behavior. I also suggest semantic ID values instead of element-type values, which become incorrect when your markup changes: `#username`, `#userlinks`